# Valgrind Memory Leak Log

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

In valgrind, we have leak logs like this

```
==15788== 480 bytes in 20 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5,016 of 5,501    

==20901== 112 (48 direct, 64 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3,501 of 5,122 

==20901== 1,375,296 bytes in 78 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5,109 of 5,122

==20901== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)    

==20901== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
```

In Valgrind's documentation, i couldn't find exact details. Can please somebody explain

I know definitely lost means - the memory allocated is not at all freed. But can what does it mean by "20 blocks" and what it means of "lost in loss record 5,016 of 5,501". And if it says 480 bytes are lost, does it mean for one run in a loop or total ..?

In the Second line ,"112 (48 direct, 64 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost", what does it means "48 direct, 64 indirect".

And i understand the meaning of"possibly lost", but does that mean valgrind is not sure if it's a leak ..?

And regarding the 4th line, i have no idea at all. I checked the call stack provided along with that 4th line. I don't notice any "jump or move".

For the 5th line, it says the uninitialised is in last line of this code snippet. I don't see any uninitialised value here.

```
char *data = new char[somebigSize];
memset(data, '\0', somebigSize);
int sizeInt = sizeof(int);
int length = 20; //some value obtained
int position = 10; 
char *newPtrVar = new char[sizeInt + 1];
memset(newPtrVar, '\0', sizeInt + 1);
memcpy(newPtrVar, &length, sizeInt);
memcpy(&data[position], newPtrVar, sizeInt);
```

Comment: That snippet doesn't look like an actual snippet, more like an approximation.

Comment: It was extracted from my code, the file had 15K lines. I just posted the exact code, where the valgrind showed usage of uninitialized value.

Comment: `It was extracted from my code, the file had 15K lines.`  Then put that block in a `main()` function, initialize those unknown values with known values, and run a simple program.  If that simple program doesn't produce those issues, then it is the 14K+ of code you didn't post that is causing these problems.  Also, why write code like that anyway?  Why not use safer constructs such as `std::vector<char>`, `std::string`, etc?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok will do that Paul, but can you please explain the other valgrind log lines

Answer (score 0):

The [valgrind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.leaks) covers this in detail. It's quite complicated - see the link for full details, but in essence you can have:

- "still reachable" (memory that is pointed to by a pointer).
- "directly lost" (memory that is not pointed to be any live pointer)
- "indirectly lost" (memory that is pointed to by a pointer that is in memory that is "directly lost)
- "possibly lost" (memory that is pointed to, but the pointer does not point to the start of the memory).

The last case could be some random pointer, and it could be something like a memory manager that allocates a redzone before the memory returned to the user.